# Arduino Nano drivers

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano

I got a Arduino Uno awhile ago and it took me awhile to set up but it worked when I downloaded the IDE. This time when I bought an Arduino Nano it doesn't pop up with the driver. Doesn't show up anywhere in device manager. I've tried to reinstall the IDE to see if that would work but it didn't. What should I do/try next?

Comment: Is it a *real* Nano or did you get some cheap POS from eBay / Amazon?

Comment: @Majenko That was quick, yes it is a real one. **Arduino Nano A000005**.

Comment: I'm not sure if the IDE comes with the FT232RL drivers any more - if it doesn't you may need to manually install them from the [ftdichip](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) website.

Comment: I downloaded a FTDI VCP driver and I ran it until nothing popped up anymore but after all of that nothing happened nothing in device manager still. Doesn't make any sound when I plug it in.

Comment: Check your usb cable.

Comment: It is on if thats what you're saying, green light on the top

Comment: That means nothing. Some cheap usb cables lack data wires. Power works but nothing else.

Comment: Well I did burn out the cables that I used last night so I'm gonna have to go find another one

Comment: How the hell do you burn out a usb cable?!?!

Comment: 12v through usb hub but I found another cable and it works lol ty for suggestions. :)